# Java installation having issues on Centos java and javac showing different version

Tags: centos, java

I have this package of java jdk-7u3-linux-x64.rpm. So I have been doing this normally yum install jdk-7u3-linux-x64.rpm. Then immediately I will do this

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java 20000

alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/javaws 20000

alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/latest/bin/javac 20000
```

Next step is this alternatives --config java and pick the latest one. Suddenly this particular machine I am having issue when I run this 2 commands it shows me different version of java and javac causing my programme can't be compiled.

Below is all the java

alternatives --config java

```
There are 4 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
   2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
   3           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java
 + 4           /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

Java version is as below

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

But my javac -version is

```
javac -version
javac 1.7.0_19
```

I am very surprised -- where does the 1.7.0_19 come from, because my installation version is just 1.7.0_03?

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: What do you get when you run "which java" and "which javac" ?

Comment: @John I get /usr/bin/java and /usr/bin/javac

Comment: Are they symlinks? If so, follow them to their ultimate actual binaries. You can also try "rpm -qf <path>" on each of them to find out what package they are owned by - preferrably using the ultimate binary after following any symlink chain.

Comment: @What are symlink I am not too sure about this. Ok what I did modified this via update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/bin/java 20000. Next I run both rpm -qf /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/java and rpm -qf /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/javac gave me jdk-1.7.0_03-fcs.x86_64

Comment: Symlinks are symbolic links. If a file is a symlink, it simply points to another file, saying "That's me over there." Do an "ls -la" on /usr/bin/java and /usr/bin/javac. If they look like one file pointing to another, it's a symlink. Follow the chain with further "ls -la"s until you come to the end. Then run "rpm -qf" against the end path.

Comment: I got this ls -la /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 May 22 13:09 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
but the rpm -qf gives me this for both rpm -qf /etc/alternatives/java 
file /etc/alternatives/java is not owned by any package  and ls -la /usr/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 23 May 22 11:37 /usr/bin/javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac

Comment: Is /etc/alternatives/java a symlink? Probably. Follow it. Keep following the chain until it's not a symlink.

Comment: Ok I done ls -la /usr/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 23 May 22 11:37 /usr/bin/javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac
[root@localhost ~]# ^C
[root@localhost ~]# ls -la /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 25 May 22 13:09 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/java/latest/bin/java
[root@localhost ~]# ls -la /usr/java/latest/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 7630 Jan 20  2012 /usr/java/latest/bin/java
and for

Comment: Javac is ls -la /usr/java/latest/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 7630 Jan 20  2012 /usr/java/latest/bin/java
[root@localhost ~]# ls -la /etc/alternatives/javac
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 48 May 22 11:37 /etc/alternatives/javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/javac so here is the problem. So it means these lines did not took proper effect 
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java 20000

alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/javaws 20000
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/latest/bin/javac 20000

Comment: I tried this command now  update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/javac 20000 yet it did not update accordinly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternatives system doesn't always work correctly with third party packages like the Java packages you're installing. You need to either use the CentOS packaged java or create the symlinks yourself without using the alternatives system/command to ensure all links are correct.

Comment: But surprisingly this is the same command I have been using for all my other centos machine and it works. So how to create those symlinks as I have been using alternative all this while.

Comment: Learn the "ln" command.

Comment: Will it be right if I just cp from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/javac into /usr/bin/javac ? Why do need the links?

Comment: I did this  ln -s /usr/java/latest/bin/javac /usr/bin/javac
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/bin/javac': File exists

Comment: any help on how to resolve this issue now?